# ndb returning a StructuredProperty subproperty by querying for a StructuredProperty

Tags: google-app-engine, database-design, python-2.7, app-engine-ndb

Hi I'm confused about how to return a StructuredProperty property (mouthful):

Say I have this example from the ndb tutorial:

```
class Address(ndb.Model):
  type = ndb.StringProperty() # E.g., 'home', 'work'
  street = ndb.StringProperty()
  city = ndb.StringProperty()

class Contact(ndb.Model):
  name = ndb.StringProperty()
  addresses = ndb.StructuredProperty(Address, repeated=True)

guido = Contact(name='Guido',
                addresses=[Address(type='home',
                                   city='Amsterdam'),
                           Address(type='work',
                                   street='Spear St',
                                   city='SF')])

guido.put()
```

I want to be able to query for city Amsterdam and have it return the type "home".

so if I did the query:

```
Contact.query(Contact.address == Address(city='Amsterdam'))
```

I would want it to return Home.

Answer (score 1):

Queries in appengine by default return the whole entity.  If I understand you correctly, you just want a field of the structured property returned, rather than the whole entity.

If this is the case, the you want to read up on projection queries.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#projection

Comment: I had perused the projection queries. That might be what I need, though getting the Zone might be sufficient. My first question would be in a repeated structuredproperty inside Zone even if I get the Zone entity how can i look for individual structured properties. aka. I'm looking for the Zone with address in Amsterdam, but I want the Amsterdam's "structured entity"(for lack of better work since there are no keys) type. Since there are no ID's or key's for structured properties how do you look for individual structured properties?  I can try to re-word this if I over complicated the question.

Comment: You don't  You can only return whole entities or named properties through a projection.  (Structured properties are not seperate entities)

Comment: You'd have to loop over the list of addresses searching for the one you need.